# How can the tangent vector to a beam of light be expressed in these 2 ways?

Tags: general-relativity, special-relativity, metric-tensor

Considering a Minkowski spacetime:

$ds^2 = -dt^2 + dx^2 + dy^2 + dz^2$

For a beam of light moving in a +ve $x$ direction I have found the tangent vector to be:

$k_\mu = B(1,1,0,0)$ where B > $0$

However, the answer in the textbook I'm using has $k_\mu = B(-1,1,0,0)$

I am not sure how the -1 comes to be in the time component, can someone shed some light on where it comes from?

The only way I can think of is if the textbook assumes $k^\mu = B(1,1,0,0)$ and then uses the metric to lower the index which introduces the negative 1 in the time component.

The question I'm asking is where does the -1 come from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A vector can be expressed as contravariant components, that is as a vector (index up), or as covariant components, i.e. as a dual vector (index down). If you calculate the tangent vector of a worldline applying the derivative of the coordinates vs. the proper time (massive particle), or vs. an affine parameter (massless particle, e.g. a photon), you get a vector, that is:
$x^\mu = (t, x, y, z)$ Cartesian coordinates in Minkowski
$u^\mu = d_\lambda x^\mu$ tangent vector
where $\lambda$ affine parameter
If you want the dual vector, you have
$u_\mu = \eta_{\mu \nu} u^\nu$ tangent dual vector
where $\eta_{\mu \nu} = diag(-1, 1, 1, 1)$ metric tensor in Minkowski
The minus sign is because of that.